# Can an employer persue a debt from a former employee?

Tags: termination

We have to terminate an employee for theft. Can we call him to request for payment for the money that he took?

Comment: I'm hard-pressed to imagine why you wouldn't be allowed to do so at least once.  I have to believe, though, that you'd be better served speaking with a lawyer and sending the request in the form of a suit to recover damages or an offer not to file criminal charges if the property is returned.

Comment: That is a matter for a lawyer. It depends heavily on legal issues in your area. Unfortunately, that means it's out of scope for this website.

Comment: You might try asking this on Law SE.  Though I would probably flesh the question out a little more.  Can I do X is never a good quesiton on SE.  How can i do X is better but only when enough detail is provided for the proper context.

Comment: I know this is off topic but couldn't you just dock it from his final paycheck? I recall from working at retail once someone stole something and they took it out of his pay. You'll have to consult a lawyer on that though.

Answer (score 2):

> Can we call him to request for payment for the money that he took?

Yes, you certainly can call him.

Whether you will be successful or not probably depends on your local laws, the stubbornness of the individual, and your willingness to pursue legal remedies.

Comment: Yes, but I don't see that you have much chance of getting the money back without a conviction.  (But IANAL, of course.)  Unless you can e.g. agree to drop criminal charges if the money's repaid.

Comment: Might be able fo file a civil case even if not criminal.(You can sue for almost anyt vaguely reasonable dispute; what happens as a result is a different question.)  But that's a question to ask a lawyer, not the Internet.

Comment: If the employee had criminal charges filed, you have a much better chance of winning in civil court, or having the former employee be required to (attempt to) pay you back. It depends on what the laws are in your neck of the woods. So like everyone else, I'd say call a lawyer!